# qtsingleapplication multiple users on the same linux machine

Tags: qt

I found the qtsingleapplication create a local file in the /tmp directory which is users shared, my question is qtsingleapplication is user specific or not, different users could have different instances running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [documented](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html#isRunning) that the function `QtSingleApplication::isRunning`

> Does not find instances of this application that are being run by a
>   different user 
>  (on Windows: that are running in another session).

Thus different users could have different instances running.

You shouldn't be worried about files created in `/tmp` by different instances. They will not interfere.